# Excel VBA: Login to Website, Pull data from table

Tags: html, vba, excel

i'm want my excel macro to go on to this website, log on, and copy the entire table and paste it on to the excel spreadsheet.

I'm not too familiar with ExcelVba and i don't know what to do after logging into the website.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub DataPulling()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim ReportURL As String
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim HTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

'set CurrentSheet as Active Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

'On the Error, go Err_Clear
On Error GoTo Err_Clear

'Create a new instance of IE
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'Declare Web Addresses
URL = "http://www.login-page.com"
ReportURL = "http://www.the-table-page.com"

ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Silent = True

'Go to the main website
ieApp.navigate URL

Do
    Loop Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = ieApp.document
    HTMLDoc.all.UserId.Value = "userid"
    HTMLDoc.all.password.Value = "password"

    For Each HTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If HTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then HTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next

ieApp.navigate ReportURL

Do While ieApp.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

'I dont know what to put here..!!??

ieApp.Quit

Set ieApp = Nothing
Set ieDoc = Nothing
```

and the source page of the website looks something like this below..

```
<div id="divDt" class="dt">
<table id="tblActiveProjects" class="display dt" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ContentA1</th>
            <th>ContentA2</th>
            <th>ContentA3</th>
            <th>ContentA4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ContentB1</th>
            <th>ContentB2</th>
            <th>ContentB3</th>
            <th>ContentB4</th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet might help you:

```
    Dim tb As Object, tr As Object, th As Object
    Dim yourValue As String 

    Set tb = HTMLdoc.getElementById("tblActiveProjects") 'tb is the Table object

    For Each tr In tb.Rows 'loop through the <tr> rows of your table
      For Each th In tr.cells 'loop through the <th> cells of your row
        yourValue = th.outerText 'your value is now in the variable "yourValue"
      Next th
    Next tr
```

The value contained in each `th` element gets temporarily stored in the variable `yourValue`. I let you decide if you want to add it to a values collection:

```
Dim myValues As New Collection
'...
    myValues.Add th.outerText
```

... or printing it into a spreadsheet cell...

```
Range("A" & j).Value = th.outerText
j = j + 1
```

... or whatever else you would like to do with your values. Please note this is a starting input, you will probably need to adjust the code to match it fully with your needs.

**EDIT - how to deal with 'object not set'**

Basically, a webpage is a file loaded from a server machine through the Internet. When you automate the web, you are "running" with VBA (a Ferrari) against a server loading an HTML file and its contents from the databases through your Internet connection (an old man on an old donkey).

In other words, you need to tell your VBA program to wait until the webpage is loaded, otherwise you risk to start looking for a variable before the server has pushed it into the webpage. You are actually already doing something like this in your code:

```
Do While ieApp.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
```

This code will loop until the statement `ieApp.Busy` will return `False`; when it's not busy anymore, then, it will release the code and let it run again.

*What might be happening to you sometimes?*

Depending on the architecture of the host server of your website, as well as on the design of the webpage, it might be that sometimes the application is released before it has actually loaded the data. Hence, when you will try to look `For Each tr In tb.Rows`, you won't find any `Rows` into your `tb` because in the moment in which your execution has `Set tb = HTMLdoc.getElementById("tblActiveProjects)`, that object was still empty.

Hence, the "non-elegant" but best solution to avoid this kind of delays is to put a physical time waiter in case of error. To talk "in code":

```
    'we turn on the error handler. If there is an error, it will ignore it and go to the next instruction
    On Error Resume Next
    'we try to set the element. We don't know how it will go...
    Set tb = HTMLdoc.getElementById("tblActiveProjects") 'tb is the Table object

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'if an error occurred, we wait for 5 seconds and then we re-try
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 5) 
        Set tb = HTMLdoc.getElementById("tblActiveProjects") 'we retry, it should be fine
        On Error GoTo 0 'we re-turn the error to 0
    End If

    On Error Resume Next 'we re-turn the error handler on
    Set whatever = tb.Rows 'we see if there's something wrong here

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'if an error occurred now, it means the table existed but was empty, so we wait for 5 seconds and then we re-set the object that this time should be filled up
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 5) 
        Set tb = HTMLdoc.getElementById("tblActiveProjects") 'we retry, it should be fine
        On Error GoTo 0 'we re-turn the error to 0
    End If        

    'we restart our code execution regularly, this time we're almost sure our browser has been able to load the content

    For Each tr In tb.Rows 'loop through the <tr> rows of your table
      For Each th In tr.cells 'loop through the <th> cells of your row
        yourValue = th.outerText 'your value is now in the variable "yourValue"
      Next th
    Next tr
```

Again, it's not a very nice solution, but with web-scraping (i.e. raw scraping of data rather than using any better API) it's all about work-arounds that work in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Hello, @Matteo, your code works great most of the time, but sometimes i get this error message of "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on your first for loop. is it possible to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JLee, sure it is. Where does it happen exactly?

Comment: it happens on this line ->   For Each tr In tb.Rows